# Strange redirection with Perl's WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl

Perl 5.36.0 with latest WWW::Mechanize 2.15.  I want to get https://web.metro.taipei/img/ALL/timetables/079a.PDF this PDF file's `Last-Modified`, in which both curl & HTTPie work well:

```
$ curl -i https://web.metro.taipei/img/ALL/timetables/079a.PDF
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/pdf
Last-Modified: Fri, 11 Nov 2022 16:20:50 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "93931790e9f5d81:0"
Date: Wed, 23 Nov 2022 05:24:16 GMT
Content-Length: 205866
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=177211688
Set-Cookie: ...

$ http -p h https://web.metro.taipei/img/ALL/timetables/079a.PDF 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 205866
Content-Type: application/pdf
Date: Wed, 23 Nov 2022 05:24:52 GMT
ETag: "93931790e9f5d81:0"
Last-Modified: Fri, 11 Nov 2022 16:20:50 GMT
Set-Cookie: ...
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=177211688
```

But with Perl WWW::Mechanize (based on LWP::UserAgent), it doesn't return the PDF file and instead the server has redirected me to root page https://web.metro.taipei/:

(btw, I need to workaround its SSL certificate verification issue due to lack of intermediate certificate on https://web.metro.taipei/ web server settings.  The `sectigo-rsa.pem` file can be obtained from https://crt.sh/?d=924467857)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;
use WWW::Mechanize;

INIT {
    # Workaround with Sectigo's intermediate CA.
    my $ua = WWW::Mechanize->new(
        agent => 'Monitoring/0.20221123',
        ssl_opts => {
            SSL_ca_file => 'sectigo-rsa.pem'
        },
    );

    my $res = $ua->get(
        'https://web.metro.taipei/img/ALL/timetables/079a.PDF',
    );

    say $res->base;

    # You can see details of redirects with:
    say Dumper $res->redirects;
}

__END__
```

Now `$res->base` is:

```
$ ./monitoring-taipei-metro.pl
https://www.metro.taipei/
```

Also for the result of `$res->headers`, you can see there is a redirect response about `https://www.metro.taipei/`:

```perl
$VAR1 = bless( {                                                                                  
                 '_content' => '',                                                                
                 '_rc' => '302',                                                                  
                 '_headers' => bless( {                                                           
                                        'content-length' => '0',                                  
                                        'client-peer' => '60.244.85.177:443',                     
                                        'location' => 'https://www.metro.taipei/',
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By capturing `WWW:Mechanize`'s raw request (using `mitmproxy`), I found these headers in the request:

```
TE:               deflate,gzip;q=0.3
Connection:       close, TE
```

It seems that `web.metro.taipei` will redirect all requests to https://www.metro.taipei/ if `Connection: TE` exists.

```
push(@LWP::Protocol::http::EXTRA_SOCK_OPTS, SendTE => 0);
```

This turns off sending TE header.

Comment: Thanks, another approach is to add `send_te => 0` to `WWW::Mechanize->new()`.